# Is there a way to log every DELETE statement with Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to log every `DELETE` statement in our database to a log file or table.  Is there a way to do this?

I thought about creating a trigger on every table, but I cannot find a way to record the SQL statement itself within a trigger.

Does Oracle support logging certain database commands, and including the full command text within the logs?  How does one enable this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does support this.  You want to look at database [Auditing](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Auditing_10gR2.php)